# Why am I not getting the same estimation of PI using a parallelized (OpenMP) algothrim copied from working code?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, montecarlo

The code below is a direct translation from a youtube video on Estimating PI using OpenMP and Monte Carlo. Even with the same inputs I'm not getting here their output. In fact, it seems like around half the value is what I get.

```
int main() {
    int num; // number of iterations
    printf("Enter number of iterations you want the loop to run for:   ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    double x, y, z, pi;
    long long int i;
    int count = 0;
    int num_thread;

    printf("Enter number of threads you want to run to parallelize the process:\t");
    scanf_s("%d", &num_thread);
    printf("\n");

#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(x,y,z,i) shared(count) num_threads(num_thread)
    {
        srand((int)time(NULL) ^ omp_get_thread_num());
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            x = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
            y = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

            z = pow(((x * x) + (y * y)), .5);

            if (z <= 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    } // END PRAGMA
    pi = ((double)count / (double)(num * num_thread)) * 4;
    printf("The value of pi obtained is %f\n", pi);

    return 0;
}
```

I've also used a similar algorithm straight from the Oak Ridge National Laboratory's website (https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/tutorials/monte-carlo-pi/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int niter = 1000000;            //number of iterations per FOR loop
    double x,y;                     //x,y value for the random coordinate
    int i;                          //loop counter
        int count=0;                //Count holds all the number of how many good coordinates
    double z;                       //Used to check if x^2+y^2<=1
    double pi;                      //holds approx value of pi
        int numthreads = 16;
 
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(x, y, z, i) shared(count) num_threads(numthreads)
    {
        srandom((int)time(NULL) ^ omp_get_thread_num());    //Give random() a seed value
        for (i=0; i<niter; ++i)              //main loop
        {
            x = (double)random()/RAND_MAX;      //gets a random x coordinate
            y = (double)random()/RAND_MAX;      //gets a random y coordinate
            z = sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));          //Checks to see if number is inside unit circle
        if (z<=1)
        {
                ++count;            //if it is, consider it a valid random point
        }
    }
        //print the value of each thread/rank
    }
        pi = ((double)count/(double)(niter*numthreads))*4.0;
        printf("Pi: %f\n", pi);
 
    return 0;
}
```

And I am have the exact problem, so I'm think it isn't the code but somehow my machine.

I am running in VS Studio 22, Windows 11 with 16 core i9-12900kf and 32 gb ram.

Edit: I forgot to mention I did alter the second algorithm to use srand() and rand() instead.

Comment: *I'm not getting here their output.* Please explain why you expect the same result whereas random values are used in the calculations?

Comment: `rand` is not thread-safe and cannot be used in a parallel OpenMP section without causing a race-condition (causing wrong results due to an undefined behaviour). OpenMP do not check if the code is thread-safe (actually, it cannot), this is your responsibility. There are few past posts about this.

Comment: The first code uses `rand` / `srand`, but these are not thread-safe.  Whatever source you got that from should be disregarded.

Comment: @273K I understand what you are saying, but that isn't a factor in this situation. They will be different yes, but it should be approximately PI. My output is half of expected which you cannot attribute to the random numbers in this case.

Comment: You did not show any output, your and their, thus it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Every single example I see in videos and websites uses rand() with this problem. Even the example from oak ridge national lab uses it, do you suggest they are incorrect?

Comment: A lot of tutorials (especially videos ones) has bogus codes. The ORNL tutorials are generally quite good but there is indeed an error which is surprising... They use `random` which is a POSIX function. The [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) explicitly states "This function should not be used in cases where multiple threads use random() and the behavior should be reproducible. Use `random_r` for that purpose.". The one of `rand` states "The function rand() is not reentrant or thread-safe". This is pretty clear. This is sad as it is a basic mistake...

Comment: Some implementations has a per-thread seed so it can work in practice, but users should not make this assumption. You can trust (standard) documentations and specification (like the OpenMP one). You can also check the OpenMP examples on the official website. They are made by OpenMP designers (typically researcher in the field). For the other kind of sources, you need to be very careful. Parallel programming is hard so mistakes are pretty frequent. I also advise you to read peer-reviewed/commented sources.

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors in the code:

1. As pointed out by @JeromeRichard and @JohnBollinger `rand\srand\random` are not threadsafe you should use a threadsafe solution.
2. There is a race condition at line `++count;` (different threads read and write a shared variable). You should use reduction to avoid it.
3. The code assumes that you use `numthreads` threads, but OpenMP does not guarantee that you actually got all of the threads you requested. I think if you got PI/2 as a result, the problem should be the difference between the requested and obtained number of threads. If you use `#pragma omp parallel for...` before the loop, you do not need any assumptions about the number of threads (ie. in this case the equation to calculate PI does not contain the number of threads).
4. A minor comment is that you do not need to use the time-consuming `pow` function.

Putting it together your code should be something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count) num_threads(num_thread)    
for (long long int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    const double x = threadsafe_random_number_between_0_1();
    const double y = threadsafe_random_number_between_0_1();
    const double z = x * x + y * y;
    if (z <= 1) {
        count++;
    }
}
double pi = ((double) count / (double) num ) * 4.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

One assumption but I may be wrong : you initialise random with time, so it may happen than different thread use the same time , which may result in same random number generated, and so the result will be really bad as you got multiple time the same values. This is a problem with the Monte-Carlo method where 2 identical points will make wrong result.

Comment: I think half of the expected value cannot be explained by identical points. In the worst case the number of iterations is practically 16 (number of threads) times smaller (due to identical points), but as long as it is high enough (like in the second code `niter = 1000000;`) it does not affect the calculated value significantly. (Using 1000 iterations the result is 3.13)